# Linux Mint screen too big

Tags: xfce, display, desktop-environment

I use Linux Mint. I did something and now my screen is too big and it moves as I move the mouse. How can I resize the screen such that it returns to the original size where everything fits onto the screen? I'm using XFCE. 
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>**-**</kbd> won't solve the issue,
neither <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ mouse scrollbar. 
I was only able to change the size of www-pages on Firefox. 
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> gives a console with good size.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and tell us what desktop environment you are using (if you don't know, at least tell us the version of Mint and we might be able to guess). It sounds like you have simply zoomed into the desktop. Try holding down the windows key and then scrolling the mouse wheel. If that doesn't work, try using the Ctrl key instead of Windows and doing the same. If that still doesn't work try other combinations. Also try pressing the `-` key instead of scrolling. Then, report back and we can take it from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution from https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/refresh-linux-desktop-without-rebooting/. Just open the terminal and run commands `xfce4-panel -r && xfwm4 --replace`

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Cinnamon on Mint 19.3.  I accidentally zoomed the desktop. 
The way out for me was to hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> and scroll forward.